# Postgres - get midnight from a given timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sql-update

I have three `timestamptz` columns: `due_at`, `starts_at`, and `ends_at`. I need to update `starts_at` and `ends_at` such that they will have the same date as `due_at` except the times will be `12:00 AM` and `11:59 PM` respectively.

`UPDATE table SET starts_at = due_at;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
update mytable set
    starts_at = date_trunc('day', due_at),        
    ends_at   = date_trunc('day', due_at) + interval '1' day - interval '1' minute
```

You could also phrase this as:

```
update mytable set
    starts_at = date_trunc('day', due_at),        
    ends_at   = date_trunc('day', due_at) + interval '23 hours 59 minutes'
```